# VNC via SSH tunnel working or not, unkown causes

Tags: ssh, vnc, remmina, tunnel, vino

I have Ubuntu 20.04.3, in two computers PC1 and PC2.
I can connect via VNC (remmina) between the two with no problem.

Now I try to use VNC via SSH tunnel.

1. Set the tunnel

   ```
    [PC1]$ ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@192.168.0.32
    bind [127.0.0.1]:5900: Address already in use
    channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5900
    Could not request local forwarding.
    Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-41-generic x86_64)
    ...
   ```
2. In remmina, connect with Protocol Remmina VNC Plugin (the same as a non-tunneled connection) to `localhost:5900`. I am asked for the password set in *Settings* -> *Sharing* -> *Screen Sharing*. I enter that password, and I get *Could not authenticate, attempting reconnection...*.

The same happens when trying PC2 -> PC1 (via SSH tunnel).

A. **How can I fix this?**

---

I have another PC3, with Win10, and I want to VNC from PC3 to both PC1/2, using tigervnc.
I can do that with no problem either.

Now I try to use VNC via SSH tunnel.
I can do that PC3 -> PC1, using a mingw64 prompt in PC3, with

1. In a mingw64 bash prompt,

   ```
   [PC3]$ ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@192.168.0.140
   bind [127.0.0.1]:5900: Address already in use
   channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5900
   Could not request local forwarding.
   Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-41-generic x86_64)
   ...
   ```
2. In tigervnc, connect to `localhost:5900`. I am asked for the password set in *Settings* -> *Sharing* -> *Screen Sharing*. I enter that password, and I already have the VNC screen in PC3.

If I try to do the same with PC3 -> PC2, I get

1. In a mingw64 bash prompt,

   ```
   [PC3]$ ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@192.168.0.32
   bind [127.0.0.1]:5900: Address already in use
   channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 5900
   Could not request local forwarding.
   Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-41-generic x86_64)
   ...
   ```
2. In tigervnc, connect to `localhost:5900`. I am asked for the password set in *Settings* -> *Sharing* -> *Screen Sharing*. I enter that password, and I get *Authentication failure*.

B. **How can I fix this?**

---

The following info may be useful:
In PC1 I have

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino
org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
org.gnome.Vino use-alternative-port false
org.gnome.Vino disable-background false
org.gnome.Vino disable-xdamage false
org.gnome.Vino alternative-port uint16 5900
org.gnome.Vino icon-visibility 'client'
org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods ['vnc']
org.gnome.Vino network-interface ''
org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect true
org.gnome.Vino mailto ''
org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
org.gnome.Vino use-upnp false
org.gnome.Vino vnc-password '<12-char string>'
org.gnome.Vino view-only false
```

In PC2 I have the same, except for

```
org.gnome.Vino vnc-password 'keyring'
```

And when I try to set the password in *Settings* -> *Sharing* -> *Screen Sharing*, I am limited to 8 characters, which is not the usual case I met.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the difference between PC1 and PC2,
which led to

```
PC3 -> PC1 (SSH tunnel): OK
PC3 -> PC2 (SSH tunnel): Failed
```

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in PC2, I had set before for security reasons `AllowTcpForwarding no`. Commenting that line, I could connect.

---

I then fixed the SSH tunnel PC1 -> PC2

1. Set the tunnel

   ```
    [PC1]$ ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 user@192.168.0.32
    Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-41-generic x86_64)
    ...
   ```
2. In remmina, connect with Protocol Remmina VNC Plugin (the same as a non-tunneled connection) to localhost:5902. I am asked for the password set in *Settings* -> *Sharing* -> *Screen Sharing*. I enter that password, and I get a remote desktop.

Same for PC2 -> PC1.