# 8 character limit in Screen Sharing password

Tags: password, desktop-sharing

I have Ubuntu 20.04.3, in two computers PC1 and PC2.

In PC1 I have

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino
org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
org.gnome.Vino use-alternative-port false
org.gnome.Vino disable-background false
org.gnome.Vino disable-xdamage false
org.gnome.Vino alternative-port uint16 5900
org.gnome.Vino icon-visibility 'client'
org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods ['vnc']
org.gnome.Vino network-interface ''
org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect true
org.gnome.Vino mailto ''
org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
org.gnome.Vino use-upnp false
org.gnome.Vino vnc-password '<12-char string>'
org.gnome.Vino view-only false
```

In PC2 I have the same, except for

```
org.gnome.Vino vnc-password 'keyring'
```

And when I try to set the password in PC2, *Settings* -> *Sharing* -> *Screen Sharing*, I am limited to 8 characters.
The usual case I met, e.g. in PC1, is not having such limit.

**How can I change this?**

It seems to be a string

```
$ gsettings range org.gnome.Vino vnc-password
type s
```

but I don't dare simply setting the value.

Comment: I understand this is a limitation of VNC. It only checks the first 8 characters of a password.  You get around this by using VNC through ssh tunnel. The ssh is more secure.

Comment: @user68186 - I missed that! Still, how do you explain the difference in `org.gnome.Vino vnc-password`? And how to change that?
I am not sure that is part of the cause for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380183/vnc-via-ssh-tunnel-working-or-not-unkown-causes).